# Google Street View Image Metadata content

Tags: python, google-maps, google-street-view

When I make a Street View Image Metadata request using

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview/metadata?size=600x300&location=eiffel%20tower,%20paris,%20france&fov=110&pitch=38&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

I get the following:

```
{
  "copyright" : "© 2017 Google",
  "date" : "2016-05",
  "location" : {
  "lat" : 48.85783227207914,
  "lng" : 2.295226175151347
  },
"pano_id" : "tu510ie_z4ptBZYo2BGEJg",
"status" : "OK"
}
```

However, I would like to have the `heading` returned. As stated in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/intro):

> heading indicates the compass heading of the camera. Accepted values
>   are from 0 to 360 (both values indicating North, with 90 indicating
>   East, and 180 South). If no heading is specified, a value will be
>   calculated that directs the camera towards the specified location,
>   from the point at which the closest photograph was taken.

Is there anyway to have this information retrieved? I'm using Python to make the API calls, and want a way to allow the user to adjust the `heading` in the event that it is not to their liking. I have had very little exposure to Javascript, and would prefer an option where the use of JS can be avoided.

Comment: Your request for the image includes (or should) the heading, not sure why you expect it in the metadata.

Comment: The heading isn't required. As stated above, if no heading is specified, the value is calculated based on the orientation of the camera in relation to the provided address. As in, I provide the address, and the heading is determined for me. Now I would like to know what that heading is.

Comment: Did you manage to calculate the heading using python?